# Can land lord prevent room sharing overnight due to religious reasons? We both pay rent separately and have two separate rooms

Tags: united-states, real-estate, landlord, texas, tenant

Landlord is trying to prevent bf and I from sleeping in one room overnight. We both have our own rooms. However I mostly just use it to change and store my stuff. He made a written agreement after I moved in and asked me to sign it. 
[image]

Comment: Where does it say "due to religious reasons"?

Comment: Do you and your boyfriend have separate leases?  Under what terms did you move in initially?

Comment: What state is this?

Comment: In addition to specifying the state, you need to clearly say whether this clause is in your current lease, confirm that this is a rooming house not a separate apartment, and whether the landlord lives in the house.

Comment: This is - rooming house in Texas. The land lord lives with us. It’s not written but that’s what was implied since the household is very Christian and conservative. We have separate leases. He moved in first. We started dating then I moved in later to the room across from his.  I think the land lord verbally talked to my bf about it once before I moved in. Which we thought: he can’t be serious. However there was no written agreement when I moved in in October 2019. The written agreement was given to the three tenants 2/15/20

Comment: Did you sign the new written agreement?  Did your boyfriend?  Is this a month-to-month lease?  When does the current lease expire?

Comment: Neither of us signed it yet. It is month to month. It did not have an expiration date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The landlord cannot terminate the lease before the end of the current lease period (the month, on whatever day is the anniversary of starting the lease), since this was not a condition of the lease. You have been notified of this new term, so starting with the next month, it is part of the conditions constituting the lease, whether you sign or not. (However, you could explicitly "decline" this clause, i.e. overtly not agree to that term, then the landlord would decide whether to renew the lease without the objectionable clause). By continuing to reside there, having been notified of this condition you accept that term, so you are bound by that condition, which is not prohibited by Texas law. 
After the end of this month, the new term would apply, and eviction for violating the lease could proceed.

Comment: I doubt that this is true in New York, at least, if the premises are leased jointly to the couple.  It is certainly not true in any state that "you are bound by the terms of the lease, whatever they are."

Comment: It certainly is clear that restrictions on  leases exist, for instance rent control, prohibition on discrimination. Simply asserting that leases are binding is not much of an answer, as that is definitely not true in general, and that leaves the question of whether it's true in this case.